# Random digraphs and expected number of neighbors

Tags: combinatorics, random

What is the expected number of neighbors of a vertex in a random digraph $D (n,p)$?

The degree of a vertex in a digraph is defined to be the minimum of in-degree and out-degree of that vertex.

If $X$ is the random variable that counts neighbors of a vertex $v$, then $x=\min \{x^+,x^-\}$, where $x^+$ and $x^-$ are random variables that count out-neighbors and in-neighbors of $v$.

Since both $x^+$ and $x^-$ are binomial random variables, it is easy to find CDF, but I am still not sure how to use that to find the expected number of neighbors.

Comment: The probability that $x$ has $k$ neighbors is $2Pr(x^+=k \wedge x^-\ge k,$ by symmetry.  It's easy enough to write down a formula for the expectation, but I don't think it will be easy to simplify it.

Answer (score -1):

Let x be the number of neighbors of a vertex v in a random digraph D (n,p) . Then E (X)= (n-1)[1-(1-p)^2].  I think this works correctly. I just figured this out.